# How optimize set of nested 'if' in one function?

Tags: php, laravel

I have such part of function:

```
$token = $this->getToken($user);

    if ('main' !== session('type') && is_null($token)) {
        $instagramProfile = $this->findInstagramProfile($user);
        $token = $instagramProfile->profile->user->api_token ?? null;
    } else {
        if (!$instagramProfile = $this->findInstagramProfile($user)) {
            $profile = create_instagram_profile($user);
            $user = $this->createUser($profile);
            $token = $user->api_token;
        } else {
            if($instagramProfile->profile->user) {
                $token = $instagramProfile->profile->user->api_token;
            } else {
                $user = $this->createUser($instagramProfile->profile);
                $token = $user->api_token;
            }
        };
    }
```

I have many scenarios:

1. param `type` which save in session;
2. instagram profile exist;
3. user exists.

In worlds - very simple, but in code it stay not understandable.

How I can optimize such part of code?

Maybe create more abstract function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what is supposed to happen in

```
    if ('main' !== session('type') && is_null($token)) {
        $instagramProfile = $this->findInstagramProfile($user);
        $token = $instagramProfile->profile->user->api_token ?? null;
    }
```

if by any chance `$instagramProfile->profile->user` happens to be `null`. Otherwise, refactoring is very straightforward. Just lift the common actions out of the `if/else` one by one:

```
    $instagramProfile = this->findInstagramProfile($user);

    if (!$instagramProfile) {
        $instagramProfile = create_instagram_profile($user);
    }   

    user = $instagramProfile->profile->user;
    if (!user) {
        $user = $this->createUser($instagramProfile->profile);
    }

    $token = $user->api_token;
```

Observe that it is just a mechanical rewrite.

PS: I presume that `create_instagram_profile` can be safely called with `null` argument; you are doing it anyway.

Comment: shouldn't `user` in `user = $instagramProfile->profile->user; if (!user)` be `$user`